# Full background image with menu in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

This example does not work, how to apply this image for full screen background?
For content block `background-image` works, I can not apply `background-image` for navigation.

```css
.menu-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;

}

.bg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497091071254-cc9b2ba7c48a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 80vh" class="bg" >
  <mat-toolbar  >
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm>
        <i class="material-icons">
          pets
        </i>

      </button>
      <span class="menu-spacer"></span>
      <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md >
        <!-- The following menu items will be hidden on both SM and XS screen sizes -->

      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row >
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill >
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav >
      <mat-nav-list>

      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav-container>

</div>
```

Comment: please remove the `height: 100%` or change to `height: 80vh` and try again. and please make  sure you need to have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` into head in html

Answer (score 2):

If I get what you want, you need to add the styling to `.mat-toolbar` class in order to make it work.

```css
.mat-toolbar {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497091071254-cc9b2ba7c48a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}
```

See this [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8uxnb4?file=src/app/toolbar-overview-example.css).

It even works [a with multi-row toolbar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thh78r?file=src/app/toolbar-multirow-example.css).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. Please change accordingly.

```
.bg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497091071254-cc9b2ba7c48a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```